# How to set up Iterm / vim so that vim can recognize alt key mapping?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, iterm2

I have read a couple of different solutions to get the alt modifiers working on mac/iterm in vim.

The first solution I see posted online is to map the special characters produced by the alt key within .vimrc. This work-around almost works but I encountered a problem with alt-e. On macos catalina, and USA keyboard, when I type alt-e it produces a `´` character and then waits to for more input. If I then type a `j` for example, the `´` turns into `j́`. This waiting for more input is problematic for mapping alt-e in vim.

The other solution I see online is to configure iterm to send the Esc+ codes with alt key presses. As it turns out, this Esc code is the same code sent to vim when you press Esc, which means mapping alt characters would have the unwanted effects such as literally pressing Esc + the character to trigger the same keybind.

How could I get this to work?

Comment: There is a third solution: using a graphical version of vim like `gvim`. I guess it would be macvim in you case. I've stopped trying to use `vim` for this reason. Still, things like `é` and `<m-i>` cannot be distinguished.

Comment: @LucHermitte My workflow involves using the command-line a lot. If I were to use a GUI vim then I think I would either have to figure out a way to embed the terminal within of the VIM, otherwise I'd have to switch OS windows pretty often which can be a pain.

Comment: I used to use `guake` a lot in the past for that exact purpose. I mapped the _pause_ key to toggle the terminal window. BTW, vim can embed a terminal now with `:term`.